# Cygwin installation missing /proc/net/tcp

Tags: cygwin

I recently installed Cygwin on my windows server, not I wanted to check what process is using what port, I've tried to use the following command:
`fuser -TERM -n tcp 25565`

Then it gave me an error,
Can't open protocolfile '/proc/net/tcp': No such file or directory

Am I missing something, or is there another way of finding out what proccess is using a specific port?

Comment: Noone has any answer? I'm a sad panda :(

Answer (score 1):

Cygwin doesn't attempt to emulate every aspect of Linux. If you want to check what process is using what port, you can run `netstat -b` as admin. Note that this is Windows's own `netstat` (most likely in `C:\Windows\System32`); Cygwin doesn't have its own `netstat`, as far as I know.

Comment: Not sure I understand why Cygwin provides the `fuser` command in the psmisc package if basic usage gives this message.

Comment: [`psmisc`](http://psmisc.sourceforge.net/) is "a set of some small useful utilities that use the proc filesystem", so it includes other things besides `fuser`. The whole package was designed for Linux, not Cygwin, but it's still useful to the extent that Cygwin implements procfs. For example, `fuser` does work for showing which Cygwin processes have a file open.